# How can I workout my upper body with an injured wrist?

Tags: weightlifting, injury, wrist, workout-types

A while back I injured my wrist, and while I have a clean bill of health now, during that time I was not able to work my upper body (delts, lats, biceps, triceps, pects).

Was there some way I could be been safely working my upper body during those weeks?

Comment: when you say workout your upper body do you mean for toning or ripping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have tried different exercises to see which strained your wrist and which did not (with light weights) - it may be that pulling exercises wouldn't strain as much as pushing or vice versa.

However, the right answer is to just stay off your wrist and let it recover. Losing a few weeks is really not that big a deal, and re-injuring yourself is.

If you feel restless during that time, take the opportunity to focus on something else - lower body work, or cardio endurance...

I had a similar scenario last summer. I injured my knee and really couldn't do any lower body exercise. I took the opportunity to really focus on my bench press and let the knee recover. I didn't end up losing that much lower body strength and have long since gained it back.